# How to make a conditional statement that checks if the page is the child of a certain page?

Tags: pages

I know that you can use `is_page` to check the current page. How to check if the current page is the child of a certain page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $post;
if($post->post_parent=='certain page'){
/// Her goes your code......
}
```

Remember 'certain page' is your parent page id.